# How to do lappend in a while loop using regexp

Tags: tcl

when I am using the while loop to match a variable using regexp I want the matched variable to form a list by using lappend.     The code is

```
set file_name [open filename.txt r]   
set newlist [list]     
while {[gets $file_name line] >= 0} {    
    regexp {cell \(\"(.*)\"} $line match cell_name  
    if {[info exists cell_name] && $cell_name != ""} { 
        puts "$cell_name"   
        lappend $newlist $cell_name   
        unset cell_name    
    }      
}

foreach item $newlist {puts $item}    
close $file_name
```

The text which it is matching is like cell ("aabbcc") where the values inside the quotes are changing. The values are getting captured by this code but it is not creating a list after appending. I need all the values as a list. Can u pls tell me where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `$` too much.

Change the line

```
lappend $newlist $cell_name_matched
```

to

```
lappend newlist $cell_name_matched
```

Otherwise you find the result in `${}`.

You should also check if you regexp finds something:

```
if {[regexp {cell \(\"(.*)\"} $line match cell_name_matched]} {
    puts "$cell_name_matched"   
    lappend newlist $cell_name_matched
}
```

The unset will probably throw an error too, leave it alone and remove it.

Comment: I am getting an error saying **Error: can't read "cell_name_matched": no such variable
        Use error_info for more info. (CMD-013)** @Johnnes Kuhn

Comment: I missed out on a line and made some changes in the code. Can u check it out now and tell me if removing a $ will do. @Johannes Kuhn