# how lappend $varname1 $varname2 will be executed

Tags: tcl

I have searched for `lappend $var1 $var2`, but don't find any exact answer, how it will be executed.

```
% set a {a b c}
a b c
% set b {d e}
d e
% puts [lappend $c $b]
can't read "c": no such variable     >>> here it throws error like variable not exist
% puts [lappend $a $b]
{d e}                      >>> here it doesn't throw any error, can someone explain it and how to print the value of $a, if $a is a new variable
% puts $$A
can't read "A": no such variable
% puts $$a
$a b c
% puts ${$a}
can't read "$a": no such variable
```

Comment: Please format your code output so that it appears as code. I think you need to add an indent to each line (see the editor hints).

Comment: Similar root cause of problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17559577/1578604)

Answer (score 5):

Tcl's got a *two level* syntax that it applies rigorously to everything. The first level is the Tcl generic syntax, which takes:

```
lappend $var1 $var2
```

and parses it out to three words: `lappend`, a word obtained by reading the variable `var1`, and a word obtained by reading the variable `var2`.

Then Tcl dispatches to the command named by the first word (`lappend`, a Tcl built-in) which applies command syntax handling. In the case of `lappend`, it's pretty simple: the first argument names a variable and the second and subsequent arguments are words to append to the list in the named variable.

In your case, the first argument that names a variable is obtained by reading another variable (`var1`) and the value to append to the list is coming from a variable (`var2`); a name like `a b c d e` is a legal variable name in Tcl, but it's really awkward to use. And the chance is *very* high that you don't want to write that: putting variable names in a variable is usually an indicator of confusing code. You *can* do it, but you hardly ever want to do it (except when you're using the variable name with `upvar`). You probably really meant to write:

```
lappend var1 $var2
```

Tcl is *very* exact about the distinction between variable names and variable contents. ***The `$` is not decorative!*** It's there to say “read this variable, right now”, and `$var1` is virtually equivalent to `[set var1]` in semantic terms. (The `$` shorthand was later, a Tcl 2.0 feature from way back in the day!)

---

Tcl also doesn't allow double-dereferencing with `$$vrbl`. In the *rare* cases you need it, you do `[set $vrbl]`. And if you do that, you probably should immediately see if you can use an array instead as that's typically a better choice…

Answer (score 1):

`lappend`'s first parameter is a variable name, not a value.  Therefore, in general, it should be:

```
lappend var1 $var2
```

where both var1 and var2 are list variables.  See the [Tcl lappend man page](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lappend.htm) for more details.